# Is there any way to load dynamic component in vuejs router..?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a project there have a scope to use multiple themes/layouts based on certain condition. I've a dashboard panel there have 5 five pre-built themes and at a time admin can choose a certain theme and based on that section front-end view will be appear, suppose admin choose ThemeOne then the router will use only ThemeOne components,

route.js

```js
const selectedTheme = 'themeTwo'
import Vue from 'vue'

import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from './views/'+ selectedTheme + '/Home.vue'

import About from './views/'+ selectedTheme + '/About.vue'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            component: About
        }
    ]
})
```

Please help...[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orkaP.png)

Comment: Hello, apu. Please, post you code here, not in an image.

Comment: @RaphaelParreira, plase have a look..

Comment: use `const Foo = () => import('/path/to/your/component.vue')` to dynamically load any needed component

Answer (score 3):

1. You can do it by lazy load:

```
...
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: () => import('./views/'+ selectedTheme + '/Home.vue')
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            component: () => import('./views/'+ selectedTheme + '/About.vue')
        }
    ]
})
```

2. Also you can use function to select component:

```
...
function setComponanet(componentName){
    return () => import('./views/'+ selectedTheme +'/'+ componentName +'.vue')
}

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: setComponanet('Home'))
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            name: 'about',
            component: setComponanet('About')
        }
    ]
})
```

3. If you dont want use dynamic path in import, you can use swtich in the function

```
function setComponanet(componentName){
    if(selectedTheme == themeOne)
    {
        switch(componentName){
            case 'Home': return () => import('./view/themeOne/Home');
            case 'About': return () => import('./view/themeOne/About');
            default: return () => import('./view/themeOne/NotFount');
        }
    }
    else if(selectedTheme == themeTwo)
    {
        switch(componentName){
            case 'Home': return () => import('./view/themeTwo/Home');
            case 'About': return () => import('./view/themeTwo/About');
            default: return () => import('./view/themeTwo/NotFount');
        }
    }
}
```

4. Another way with dynamic routes is using functional component

```
...
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/:theme/:compName',
            name: 'theme',
            component: Theme
            props: (route)=>({ selectedComp: route.params.theme + route.params.compName }) //selectedComp: themeOneHome
        }
    ]
})

// in Theme.vue

import themeOneHome from './themeOne/Home'
import theOneAbout from './themeOne/About'
import themeTwoHome from './themeTwo/Home'
import theTwoAbout from './themeTwo/About'

const components = {
  themeOneHome,
  themeOneAbout,
  themeTwoHome,
  theTwoAbout
}
export default {
  functional: true,
  props: ['selectedComp'],
  render(h, ctx) {
    return h(components[ctx.props.selectedComp], ctx.data, ctx.children)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to access the route path params at the point of assigning the component?  So if I was using a switch for example, could the expression be based on a path parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can load all your themes in your component and load a theme based on a variable.

Then, you can create any way to select your theme. For example, you can create a dropdown.

```
<template>
    <component :is="themeSelector"></component>
</template>

<script>
    import fooTheme from 'fooTheme'
    import fooTheme2 from 'fooTheme2'
    import fooTheme3 from 'fooTheme3'

    export default {
        name: 'fooParent',
        components: {
            fooTheme,
            fooTheme2,
            fooTheme3,
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                themeSelector: 'fooTheme2'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is it bad? Is it a bad practice, or has a bad performance? How do you use this `cons Foo` to load components dynamically?

Comment: @AndrewShmig, do you have working sample or any refference code..?

Comment: @RaphaelParreira, that'll not help for my case.

Comment: why not? we can try another approach

Comment: As i said ,i 've five different theme and all have its indivisual structure. So, suppose five pages and routes are likely , mydomain.com/home,mydomain.com/about, mydomain.com/shop, mydomain.com/contact etc.. I've selected themeOne then how do you manage route configuration for the currently selelected theme...? plz ans..

Comment: ohh... you want that it be passed through URL, right? we can do that... because we have some options... you can access mydomain.com/theme2/home and access this page with theme2... or you can access this page and then choose theme2... or store this selection in a cookie